# Why doesn't this selector work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I would like to select all jquery UI button that live inside all `<div>`s which belong to the .view class. With that in mind, I've written the following pieces of code, none of which do what I want.

**What I want is**, like I said, to return all elements whose class is `.ui-button` that live inside an element whose class is `.view`.

```
    $(".view").find('.ui-button').each(function(index){
        console.log(index);
    })

    $(".view .ui-button").each(function(index){
        console.log(index);
    })

    $(".view > .ui-button").each(function(index){
        console.log(index); 
    });
```

I've taken a screenshot so you guys can see that there are indeed JqueryUI buttons living inside that `<div>`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oefai.jpg

Thanks In advance.

**EDIT**

I've tried pushing the including of the script to last thing before closing the  tag.. still nothing...

Then I tried something that I usually do when working with asynchronous requests (is that the case here??) .. **wrapping everything in a setTimeout call with 500 ms delay.. It worked.**

Does this make sense?

Comment: *"...none of which do what I want."* Can you be more specific about what you're expecting? The selectors look fine to me.

Comment: Works in a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/G7eRX/

Comment: I see. Any idea why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: Could it be that jQuery adds that class to the button *after* your selector is running?

Comment: It worked when I wrapped all the calls in a setTimeout with 500 ms delay.....WTF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is caused by the fact that you are calling the jQueryUI function `button()` which adds the class `ui-button` to the element after your selector is running.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Rva8K/) example, which demonstrates that this is at very least feasible.

The solution, therefore, is to ensure you call `button` before trying to manipulate using the `ui-button` class, or use some other class to identify the elements you're trying to select. The second point there is an important one; you must already have another class on those elements to enable you to select them to apply the `button()` function.

Comment: Already pushed the script include to last thing before </body>.. Still nothing.

Comment: @Felipe, if the code that calls `button()` resides in a `ready` handler, you have to make sure the code in your question also resides in a `ready` handler (either the same or another one). Otherwise, it will run before the calls to `button()` even if it's located below all the other scripts in the page.

Answer (score 1):

When does your script run? It's very likely you've included it before the jQueryUI library which causes you to search for the classes before they've been added.

As a general rule, custom JavaScript files and scripts should be placed at the very bottom, right before the closing `</body>`

Comment: Specifically, only deferrable scripts should be placed at `</body>`